# Issue on Displaying Bootstrap Popover on First Click After Hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://www.bootply.com/vhV5OgZqI6) and let me know why I am not able to display popover on first click after hiding it by `.data-date` click event?

```
var appcontent = '<button class="btn btn-primary data-date">Close Popover</button>'; 
$(".map").popover({
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: function() { return $(window).width() < 975 ? 'bottom' : 'right'; },
        html: 'true',
        title : '<span class="" style=""><strong>What Date is today?</strong></span>'+
                '<button type="button"  class="btn btn-default close"\
     onclick="$(&quot;#pop-captcha&quot;).popover(&quot;hide&quot;);">x</button>',
        content : appcontent
  }).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    var popup = $(this);
    $(this).parent().find("div.popover .close").click(function() {
      popup.click();
    });
  });        

$(document).on("click", '.data-date', function(){
    $('.map').popover('hide');
});
```

I already tried some solutions on google and stack overflow but they are not working here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are hiding the popover on .data-data button click and the popover is not actually closed so when you are clicking on .map div again it toggles the open state for popover to closed and on next click it again opens it. Hope that makes sense.

Workaround is to call click() method of .map itself as done for close (x) button which will toggle the popover state.

```
$(document).on("click", '.data-date', function(){
   $('.map').click();
});
```